# How to simplify multiplication of roots

Tags: calculus, roots

Could someone help with calculating?

$$\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{5} 6]{3-2\sqrt 2}\cdot \sqrt[\leftroot{10}\uproot{5} 3]{2+\sqrt 2} \cdot \sqrt[\leftroot{10}\uproot{5} 6]{32}$$

I tried to simplify the third root:

$$ \sqrt[\leftroot{10}\uproot{5} 6]{32} = \sqrt[\leftroot{10}\uproot{5} 6]{2^5}  $$

Comment: Raise the whole stuff to power $6$. You will be surprised

Comment: Hint. $3-2\sqrt{2} = (\sqrt{2}-1)^2$.

Comment: $3-2\sqrt{2}=(\sqrt{2}-1)^2$

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt[6]{3-2\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sqrt[6]{32} &= \sqrt[6]{\bigl(3-2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\cdot\bigl(2+\sqrt{2}\bigr)^{2}\cdot{32}}\\
&= \sqrt[6]{\bigl(3-2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\cdot\bigl(6+4\sqrt{2}\bigr)\cdot{32}}\\
&= \sqrt[6]{\bigl(3-2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\cdot\bigl(3+2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\cdot{64}}\\
&= \sqrt[6]{(9-8)\cdot 64}\\
&= 2
\end{aligned}
$$